# No `echo` Output in `RUN` Command

Tags: docker

Given:

```
$cat Dockerfile
FROM java:openjdk-8u72-jdk 

RUN echo "..."
RUN echo $FOO
```

Then I built it via `docker build .`:

```
$docker images
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED              VIRTUAL SIZE
<none>              <none>              sha256:02914        About a minute ago   642.8 MB
java                openjdk-8u72-jdk    sha256:081ce        3 days ago           642.8 MB
```

But, when I run it, I don't see any echo:

```
$docker run -it -e FOO='bar' sha256:02914
root@26d514890b3a:/#
```

Why don't I see the two `echo` outputs?

Answer (score 5):

`RUN` commands in your Dockerfile execute as part of the `docker build` process.  They are for making changes to the image that you are creating.  They are not executed when you start a container from the resulting image.

The `CMD` and `ENTRYPOINT` directives describe commands that will be executed when a container boots.  Read [the documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/) for more details.